# Can't INSERT into Google Fusion Tables by two-legged OAuth in Python

Tags: python, google-fusion-tables, service-accounts, google-apis-explorer

I try to work with Google Fusion Table using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server (two-legged) by the next code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials\
    .from_json_keyfile_name('***file-name***.json', scopes)
fusiontables = build('fusiontables', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

obj = fusiontables.query().sql(sql='select * from ***table-id***').execute()
```

Everything is OK when I read from the table, but when I try to insert some data:

```
obj = fusiontables.query().sql(
    sql="INSERT INTO ***table-id*** (Location, Number) VALUES('Paris', 1234)")\
    .execute()
```

I got the error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?alt=json&sql=INSERT+INTO+***table-id***+%28Location%2C+Number%29+VALUES%28%27Paris%27%2C+1234%29 returned "Forbidden">
```

Question: does someone know what I am doing wrong to implement insertion into Google Fusion Table?

**UPD:**

Found that oauth2client is deprecated, tried to make a query by [google.auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io) and Requests as it is described in the [docs](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html):

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('***filename***.json')
if credentials.requires_scopes:
    credentials = credentials.with_scopes(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'])

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

r = authed_session.post('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query', 
data={
    "sql": "***My SQL***",
    "hdrs": True,
    "typed": True,
})
```

As the preview, I got the same result: success on **SELECT** and 403 on **INSERT**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bought ways are the right and workable. The reason was that I need to add the permission to access to the table in the [site](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource).

Add this permission by email, that you can get from the credential file.